# find the roots of a complex number

Tags: complex-analysis

Find the fourth roots of 1+sqrt(3)i.

What I did was:

Let z=1+sqrt(3)i, so |z|=r=2 and arg(z)=π/3

So, in polar form: z=2(cos(π/3)+isin(π/3)). Therefore, z^1/4=[2(cos(π/3)+isin(π/3))]^1/4.

Using r^1/n[cos((θ+2πk)/n)+isin((θ+2πk)/n)], where k is an integer, I found the roots.

Is my thinking right?

Thank you in advance for your time and answers.

John

Comment: $k$ will assume $n$ in-congruent values like $\{0,1,2,\cdots,n-2,n-1\}$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your reasoning is correct, and your answer is correct so long as you ended up with $4$ distinct complex numbers whose $4$th powers are all $1+i\sqrt3$.